# SwiftUI: How to select items in a menu using the Picker View?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

I was wondering how to create a menu with selectable items in SwiftUI. Since I couldn't find any example on the web, see my answer below... :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually quite easy and requires Xcode 12 and macOS 11 or iOS 14:

```
@State var sortKey = 0

...

Menu(content: {
    Picker("Sort by", selection: $sortKey) {
        Text("Date").tag(0)
        Text("Name").tag(1)
        Text("Love").tag(2)
    }
}
```

If you add `.pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())` the menu will become a submenu called "Sort by", otherwise it is just part of the other items of your menu.